# Is the fixed point set of an involution on a topological manifold a submanifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $f:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism of a topological manifold with $f^2=\mathrm{id}$.

Is each connected component of $\{x\in X \mid f(x)=x\}$ a topological submanifold?

Comment: In the case of a differentiable manifold $X$, I think you can use $T_pX\circ T_pX = T_p \text{id} = I$ and fiddle around with ranks. However, I don't immediately see an approach for topological manifolds.

Comment: Related: [Problem 44 in Eilenberg's list of open problems](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969448?seq=14). Though the list is a bit old so I don't know if the question has been resolved.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238939/is-the-fixed-set-of-a-smooth-involution-a-submanifold

Comment: @HSN:  One can do even better.  Equipping $X$ with a Riemannian metric, average over $f$ to obtain an $f$-invariant Riemannian metric.  It is easy to show that the fixed point set of an isometry is a totally geodesic submanifold.

Answer (score 15):

No, the connected components of the fixed points of $f$ need not be a manifold. I can give an example of a homeomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ with $f^2=\rm id$, whose set of fixed points is connected (in fact, contractible), but is not a manifold.

Let $X=B\times\mathbb{R}$, where $B$ is Bing's [dogbone space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogbone_space), and define $f\colon X\to X$ by $f(b,r)=(b,-r)$. This is clearly a homeomorphism with $f^2=\rm id$ and $\lbrace x\in X\colon f(x)=x\rbrace=B\times\lbrace0\rbrace\cong B$. It is known that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, but the dogbone space $B$ is not a topological manifold. Also, $B$ is contractible, as its product with $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible.

*Note: Bing's construction of the dogbone space was published in May 1957<sup>1</sup>, and the fact that its product with $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}^4$ was demonstrated in 1959<sup>2</sup>. Eilenberg's list of open problems linked to by Willie Wong in the comment to the question dates back to April 1949<sup>3</sup>. So, it is entirely plausible that the problem was indeed open when Eilenberg published his list.*

---

<sup>1</sup> A Decomposition of $E^3$  into Points and Tame Arcs Such That the Decomposition Space is Topologically Different from $E^3$, R. H. Bing, Annals of Mathematics Second Series, Vol. 65, No. 3 (May, 1957), pp. 484-500. ([Link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970058))

<sup>2</sup> The Cartesian Product of a Certain Nonmanifold and a Line is $E^4$, R. H. Bing, Annals of Mathematics Second Series, Vol. 70, No. 3 (Nov., 1959), pp. 399-412. ([Link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970322))

<sup>3</sup> On the Problems of Topology, Samuel Eilenberg, Annals of Mathematics Second Series, Vol. 50, No. 2 (Apr., 1949), pp. 247-260. ([Link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969448))

Comment: Ah, beautiful! I've been searching for constructions like this and wasn't looking at the right place.

Comment: And lo, it was already mentioned in the [MathSciNet review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=107228) that one of the corollaries of Bing's construction in your item 2 is precisely the answer to this question. Bravo!